# Condition and action missing from Workflows in SharePoint designer 2010

Tags: 2010, workflow, designer

I was trying to add conditions / Actions to my SharePoint workflow through SP Designer 2010 and realised they had gone missing. I re-installed the designer to no avail. Any idea what is wrong?

I am trying to add those to a List Workflow. Screenshot below. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this problem? I have the same issue and am looking for any guidance I can get. Thanks Shawn

Comment: Try clearing your SP Designer cache. I think it is at C:\Users\\[your account]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache. Just delete all of the files in it and then reopen Designer

Comment: You will have to close designer while doing that btw

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in SharePoint designer. Opening up a SharePoint workflow an seeing all the conditions blank has given me a lot of **consternation**!

### Step 1: Make sure SharePoint Designer is patched to the latest version. As of this writing the install steps are (for 32-bit version):

1. **SharePoint Designer 2013 Installer:**

   - Download URL: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35491
   - Publish Date: 10/4/2016
   - File Name: sharepointdesigner_32bit.exe
   - Version: 10.0.4420.1017
2. **Patch 1:** Service Pack 1 for Microsoft SharePoint Designer 2013 (KB2817441) 32-Bit Edition

   - Download URL: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download
   - Publish Date: 2/18/2014
     /details.aspx?id=42015
   - File Name: spdsp2013-kb2817441-fullfile-x86-en-us.exe (308.2 MB)
   - Version: 10.0.4569.1503
3. **Patch 2:** Update for Microsoft SharePoint Designer 2013 (KB3114721) 32-Bit Edition

   - Download URL: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53364
   - Publish Date: 7/26/2016
   - File Name: spd2013-kb3114721-fullfile-x86-glb.exe (11.2 MB)
   - Version: 15.0.4849.1000

After you have installed and patched SharePoint Designer 2013 the version will be: 15.0.4849.1000. You can verify this by opening SharePoint Designer and going to:
File Menu >> Account >> About SharePoint Designer

### Step 2: Clear your SharePoint Designer Cache:

1. Close SharePoint designer if it is open
2. Using Windows explorer, go to: %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache
3. Delete everythig inside that folder
4. Now go to: %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache
5. Delete the contents of that folder as well

### Step 3: Optional: stop SharePoint Designer from using its cache:

1. Open SharePoint Designer
2. Navigate to the “File” menu. Then go to Options >> General >> Application Options
3. On the “General” tab, under the “General” heading, deselect “Cache site data across SharePoint Designer sessions”
4. Press OK to save the changes

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in SP Designer 2013 when trying to edit a 2010 platform workflow on a SP2013 server.  It turned out to be a missing WSS.ACTIONS file.  On the server, check the hive \TEMPLATE\1033\Workflow folder for this file.  It's an XML file containing the conditions and actions available.  If not found, it cannot display the actions.

Comment: Need to add that it doesn't take effect immediately.  You'll need to restart the server or wait overnight for the background processes to refresh (cache?)